# ¿porque no puedo atualizar a ubuntu 20.04 desde software app?

Tags: ubuntu

intento actualizar a ubuntu 20.004 desde ubuntu software pero en la parte de preparando la actualizacion, se detiene como  se ve en la imagen, luego se cierra:[instalar de 18 a la version 20.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BnVB.png)

[image: aqui se detiene]

lo intente con este comando desd la terminal sudo do-release-upgrade, y  arroja lo que se ve en la imagen.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

actualizando los repositorios con sudo apt update no arroja ningun error:

soy nuevo en ubuntu, agradezco su ayuda porfavor.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es un problema de programación, tal como se establece en el [help/on-topic]. Esta pregunta podría ser formulada en [su] o en [ubuntu.SE]